# Norm of an Operator on $L^2(\mu)$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, measure-theory, normed-spaces

We are given that $(X,\Omega,\mu)$ is a $\sigma-$finite measure space, with $A:L^2(\mu)\to L^2(\mu)$ given by 
$$(Af)(x)=\int_X K(x,y)f(y)d\mu(y),$$ where $K\in L^2(\mu\times\mu)$. I am trying to show that $\|A\|\leq\|K\|$.  This question is part of an old prelim exam in analysis; I'm studying to take my own prelim.

I have the following:
\begin{align}
\lVert (Af)(x)\rVert_{L^2(\mu)} &= \left( \int_X\left| \int_X K(x,y)f(y)d\mu(y) \right|^2 d\mu(x)\right)^{1/2}\\
&\leq \left( \int_X \left( \int_X|K(x,y)| \cdot \lVert f\rVert d\mu(y) \right)^2 d\mu(x)\right)^{1/2}\\
&=\lVert f\rVert \cdot\left( \int_X \left( \int_X|K(x,y)| d\mu(y) \right)^2 d\mu(x)\right)^{1/2}
\end{align}

Does it look like I'm on the right track? If so, where do I go from here? Does something justify me in just setting my final expression above to be less than or equal to $\lVert f \rVert \cdot \left( \int_X \int_X |K(x,y)|^2d\mu(y)d\mu(x) \right)^{1/2}$?

Comment: As a notational comment, note that you want to estimate the norm of the function $Af$. So the proper notation is $\|Af\|_{L^2}$, without the $x$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using the infinity norm of $f$, which is irrelevant, and you are not using that $K$ is in $L^2$.

The natural way is, using Cauchy-Schwarz,
\begin{align}
\|Af\|_2^2&= \int_X\left| \int_X K(x,y)f(y)d\mu(y) \right|^2 d\mu(x)\\ \ \\
&\leq\int_X\left|\left(\int_X|K(x,y)|^2\,d\mu(y)\right)^{1/2}\,\|f\|_2\right|^2\,d\mu(x)\\ \ \\
&=\|f\|_2^2\,\int_X\int_X|K(x,y)|^2\,d\mu(y)\,d\mu(x)\\ \ \\
&=\|f\|_2^2\,\|K\|_2^2.
\end{align}
So $\|A\|_2\leq\|K\|_2$.

Comment: Thank you, I have written up a proof that I believe works, on the basis of your suggestion of using Cauchy-Schwarz. I don't quite understand, though, the way you got about it, and specifically how to generate your second line. In my own proof, I use C-S to go from the first line to: $\leq \int_X \left(\int_X |K(x,y)|^2 d\mu(y)\right) \left( \int_X |f(y)|^2 d\mu(y)\right) d\mu(x)$. This leads to the same result you got. Could you say whether my way is still correct, and also how your second line is generated?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I did in my second line.

Comment: I see; I had misread the scope of your parens.